# React class change in a extend the generic State/Prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Basically I have a ViewMaster with many many Functions that gets somewhere in a wrapper => components executed

Now I want to have a different but mostly the same View that needs some extra Functions. Now 2 states are changing its type from

```
interface ViewState {
something:something
...
}
```

to

```
interface NewViewState extends ViewState {
change:change
}
```

But how am I able to do this.

My ViewMaster looks like this

```
class ViewMaster extends React.Component<ViewProps,ViewState>{}
```

and my new View

```
class ViewNew extends ViewMaster
```

But how am I able to set a new ViewState generic?

EDIT: Thinking about it, I can simply change the interface ViewState
to

```
interface ViewState {
change:change|something
}
```

But still It would be intresting to know

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can do this. Given that your base component is a React Component and it already has parameterization I would do something like this:

`class ViewMaster<P = ViewProps, S = ViewState> extends React.Component<P, S>{}`

and then

`class ViewNew extends ViewMaster<ViewProps, NewViewState>{}`

Comment: When I change to

 
```class ViewMaster<P = ViewProps, S = ViewState> extends React.Component<P, S>{}```

I get the Error Message


 ```Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Readonly<P> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.ts(2339)```

**and** 

```Type '{ data: any; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<S>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'data' does not exist in type 'Readonly<S>'.ts(2322)```

Comment: @Stuhl where are you defining `data`?

Comment: I set it as a state all my props and states are not working.
But I read anyway that Inheritance is not the thing someone should do in React, and this was essentially I was aiming for. So I will redesign my class to be only an interface for my other views. And life with the duplicated code